# blob.uploadtext to the same blob from multiple threads

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

A beginner question but I could not find a definite answer anywhere else.

What will happen if I use blob.uploadtext() to update the same blob at the same time from two different threads? Will the latter just fail? Or the latter just overwrite?

Also, what happens if I read from the blob while the uploadtext() is in progress? Will the read return a previous version? Or will the read fail? If the read fails, should I retry?

In my scenario, I have multiple instances of the worker role that may update the same blob (of size 10 MB) from time to time. I do not really care about who wins the write as long as they do not corrupt the blob and reading the blob is not blocked for a long time.

Update: I wrote a sample program to upload a 5MB file to the same blobreference from 3 different threads. What I found out is this:
1. If the thread reuse the blobReference object, then the second and third thread will get the MD5 not match exception. But the first thread still can successfully  finish the uploading.
2.If each thread create their own BlobClient/BlobReference object, then all the upload will succeed and the actual blob content matches with the one that finished the last.

However, after I increased the size of the blob upload to a 10MB file, I am getting a StorageClientException: The specified block list is invalid. What is worse is that the blob content is somehow 0 bytes after this exception. So my blob upload failed and wiped out the blob content. That seems to be  a pretty serious problem. Any ideas?

At below is the sample code:

```
        Task[] tasks = new Task[6];

        tasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoUpload(BlobClient, testStreams, 0));
        tasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadBlob(BlobClient,0));
        tasks[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoUpload(BlobClient, testStreams, 1));
        tasks[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadBlob(BlobClient, 1));
        tasks[4] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoUpload(BlobClient, testStreams, 2));
        tasks[5] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadBlob(BlobClient, 2));

        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

DoUpload uses the following to upload:

```
        blob.UploadFromStream(streams[i]);
```

Thanks.